# Spring Security not login to REST-created users from Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

I have a question. The fact is that when using Spring Security, the application for some reason reads only those users who were in the database at the time the application was launched, as well as those users who were added using the `CommandLineRunner` (that is, during the application launch). Those users that were created via REST after the application was launched will only be available after the application is restarted. What to do in this case? Repositories are imported into an object (via `@Autowired`) and not into a specific method (via parameters and local fields), because those methods don't work.

Answer (score 0):

My bug now solved by delete `@JsonIgnore` in password field in Entity. This is victory!